# How to make sure a string only has only certain allowed chars in it in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm making a basic calculator program that takes its inputs in the form of "num1 num2" from a user. I am working on making it so only that format of input is accepted.

This is C#. I have already tried using a whitelist array of all numbers and a space as both string[] and char[]. I have also tried Regex as well as a hybrid regex and checking for white space. none of them worked for some reason.

```cs
string input = "";
int numCheck = 0;
Regex whiteList = new Regex("^[1234567890]$");
do
{
  numCheck = 0;
  Console.Write("Please input the two numbers you wish to use seperated by a space: ");
  input = Console.ReadLine();
  if (input.IndexOf(" ") == -1 || input.Length <= 2 || input.Substring(input.IndexOf(" ")+1).IndexOf(" ") != -1 || (!whiteList.IsMatch(input) && !input.Any(x => Char.IsWhiteSpace(x))));
  {
    Console.WriteLine($"You entered \"{input}\" You did not enter two numbers seperated by a space, please try again.");
    numCheck = 1;
  }
} while (numCheck == 1);
```

I'm expecting an input of "1 1" to pass this check. but it does not.

Comment: You need a `@"^[0-9]+ [0-9]+$"` or `@"^[0-9]+\s[0-9]+$"` or `@"^[0-9]+\s+[0-9]+$"` regex

Comment: A calculator should use Decimal.TryParse().

Comment: You said "number", did you mean "single digit integer"?

Comment: Hi Evan, welcome to SO. When working with regex I've found https://regex101.com/ to be a very useful tool, mainly due to its breakdown and explanation of each individual part of your pattern.

Comment: any two whole numbers should work for this. so "11 256" should work as well as "1 1"

Comment: I think using a regex is a bit too much, you can split the input by space, check if there is two items then check if each of them is an `int` by using the `Int32.TryParse` method.

Comment: do you accept `Int32` only, or *arbitrary long* integers will do, e.g. `"123456789012345678901234567890 1"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some changes:

- Using `string.Split` is an easier way to go about getting the left/right numbers. You can then check for exactly 2 parts.
- You need a `+` symbol in your regex which states 1 or more, otherwise your regular expression will test false if the integer is over 1 digit in length.

There are other ways to accomplish this same thing like using `int.TryParse` but this works fine for what you described you needed.

---

```
string input = "";
int numCheck = 0;
Regex whiteList = new Regex("^[1234567890]+$");
do
{
    numCheck = 0;
    Console.Write("Please input the two numbers you wish to use seperated by a space: ");
    input = Console.ReadLine();
    var numbers = input.Split(new []{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    if (numbers.Length != 2 || !numbers.All(num => whiteList.IsMatch(num)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You entered " + input + " You did not enter two numbers seperated by a space, please try again.");
        numCheck = 1;
    }
}
while (numCheck == 1);
```

[dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zsatXq)

Comment: This Solved it! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you do not need to do a regex, something like this can work:

```
var values = input.Split(' ');
int value;
if (values.Length == 2 && values.All(v => int.TryParse(v, out value)) 
{
    //do stuff
}
```

The full solution could look like this:

```
string input = "";
bool success = false;
while (!success) 
{
    Console.Write("Please input the two numbers you wish to use seperated by a space: ");
    input = Console.ReadLine();

    var values = input.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    if (values.Length != 2 || !values.All(v => int.TryParse(v, out int value))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"You entered \"{input}\" You did not enter two numbers separated by a space, please try again.");
    }
    else 
    {
        success = true;
    }
}
```

IMHO, there is nothing wrong with the `do..while` but since you're already using  a loop variable, I think using just `while` communicates better at the outset that you are entering a loop that is dependent on the success of the process below it.

Comment: `int.TryParse(v, out int value)` in order to get rid of `int value;` declaration (move it into `TryParse`)

Comment: I suggest adding `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` to `Split`: let's be nice and tolerate several spaces in a row, e.g. "123      456"

Answer (score 0):

The regex should be three parts:
`(number) (space) (number)`
So the regex should be
`(\d+)  (\d+)`.
You can also check if the length of the matched part equals the length of input - if not, it means the input contains something else.

[Regex.Match(String) at MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match?view=netframework-4.8#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Match_System_String_)